# Does the atomic decorator affect all the methods in the chain in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models set up in Django:

```
from django.db import models, transaction


class X(models.Model):
    ...

    def do_something(self):
        ...
        self.save()


class Y(models.Model):
    ...
    x = models.ForeignKey(X, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def do_something(self):
        ...
        self.save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Y, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x.do_something()


class Z(models.Model):
    ...
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Z, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.y.do_something()
```

Basically, whenever a `Z` object is saved, this triggers the `do_something()` method in the `Y` object, which then saves itself, and in doing so, triggers the `do_something()` method in the `X` object.

I want the whole chaining to be atomic, so that if a `Z` object is saved, its corresponding `Y` and `X` objects must be saved as well. I have the decorator only in the `save()` method in the `Z` class. Is this the correct way to do this? Or, should the decorator be added to all the other methods in the chain? Does the decorator automatically affect all the methods in the chain or should it be explicitly added? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The atomic transaction covers all that happens from the point where `Z.save()` is started until it has ended. So, your other `save()` calls are included.

Comment: @KlausD. So my current set up should work without any issues right?

Comment: `@atomic` is usually applied to the view, though.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Could you explain a bit more on that?

Comment: This is a correct way to handle transaction. You can check this, just put `raise` before `self.y.do_something()` and verify your database.